# Hyper-V Replication Failed - Self Signed Certificates

Tags: certificate, replication, hyper-v

I have 2 servers running Hyper-V. Both servers are off domain and part of the WORKGROUP.

I have setup one of the servers to act as a Hyper-V Replica making use of self-signed certificates. I followed the below guide:
[Setup 2 Hyper-V 2016 Servers, enable Hyper-V Replica with self-created certificates and connect to Server Manager on Windows](https://medium.com/@pbengert/setup-2-hyper-v-2016-servers-enable-hyper-v-replica-with-self-created-certificates-and-connect-to-fceef21c8b8e)

For a few months now, the replication has been working successfully without any issues. Then yesterday, we started receiving Critical replication errors. see image below: 
Hyper-V received a digital certificate that is not valid from the Replica server. The specified cert is self signed (0x80092007)
[See Screenshot Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ro5s2.png)

I have tried repeating the process of creating a new set of certificates, tried restarting both servers, but still no luck of resolving this issue.  Strange that it just recently started failing, could this be due to some windows update or Hyper-V update relating to compatibility with self-signed certificates?
Can anyone advise how to resolve this?

Thanks & Regards

Rogan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We identified the problem was due to a third party software causing a conflict on port 443. Removing this application resulted in the cert working correctly again and no more error.

Answer (score 1):

reg add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Virtualization\FailoverReplication" /v DisableCertRevocationCheck /d 1 /t REG_DWORD /f

google DisableCertRevocationCheck

Comment: Thanks onestone, I did try this but was still having the same error. updated with answer above. Thanks for your valuable input.